# How to animate image change in ScrollView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

i have a scrollview that contains an array of image, I would like to animate it changing image from right to left. My scrollView:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

var imageArray = [UIImage]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.frame = view.frame
    imageArray = [UIImage(named:"image3")!,UIImage(named:"image4")!,UIImage(named:"image1")!]

    for i in 0..<imageArray.count{
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.image = imageArray[i]
        let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.scrollView.frame.width, height: 205)

        scrollView.contentSize.width = scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    }
        startAnimating()


}
```

and for animation I did it with :

```
func startAnimating() {
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: .repeat, animations: {
        self.scrollView.center.x += self.view.bounds.width

    }, completion: nil)
}
```

However, it is moving from left to right and not right to left, plus it's not changing images...How should i go about this? Any guidance is much appreciated! Thank you

Comment: For simplicity use collectionview with pagination property. Make your coding simple.

Comment: I would second @dahiya_boy's suggestion that you go a collection view approach. There are lots of great examples out there and it's a more standard approach that you will be able to reuse/tweak.

Comment: but in collectionview we would still be able to swipe left and right?

Answer (score 2):

You're moving the scrollview within it's parent view. The image views are children of the scrollview (they're inside the scrollview), so they're simply moving with it.

To scroll the content *within* your UIScrollView you should be using its contentOffset property:

```
var newOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
newOffset.x += scrollView.frame.size.width
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options, .repeat, animations: {
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = newOffset
})
```

Also, you shouldn't be using `animateKeyFrames` for this. Use the `animate(withDuration:delay:options:animations)` method instead.

It's also worth thinking about whether a UIScrollView is the right choice here, and it really comes down to how many images are going to inside it.

If it's always going to be a small number of images, then a scrollview is a fine choice.

However, if there are ever going to be a larger number images to display, then UICollectionView would be a better choice as it reuses its subviews.